# Javascript Filter Function: How do I make this filter out the green fruits?

Tags: javascript, filter

```
var fruits = [
    {name: 'nectarine',   color: 'orange'},
    {name: 'grape',       color: 'purple'},
    {name: 'banana',      color: 'yellow'},
    {name: 'grapefruit',  color: 'orange'},
    {name: 'watermelon',  color: 'green'},
    {name: 'strawberry',  color: 'red'},
    {name: 'apple',       color: 'red'},
    {name: 'pear',        color: 'green'},
    {name: 'pineapple',   color: 'yellow'},
    {name: 'kiwi',        color: 'green'},
    ];

    var green = [];
    for(var i=0; i<fruits.length; i++){
        if(fruits[i].color ==='green')
        green.push(fruits[i]);
    }
```

How do I make this filter out the green fruits, while still using a for loop?

Thank you very much in advance for your assistance!

Comment: what do you mean by filter out... do you want to remove those from `fruits`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/j8nzasqh/

Comment: I want to filter out the green fruits. I want to function to print out watermelon, pear, kiwi.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gz09med3/1/ ?

Comment: Your code already filters for the green fruits. What's wrong with it? Do you mean filter OUT (which would mean to remove, exclude), or filter IN which means to keep, retain?

Comment: I would like to return the 3 green fruits, but when I do I only want to see their names. That being watermelon, pear, kiwi.

Comment: If you only need the names - `green.push(fruits[i].name);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fruits = [
    {name: 'nectarine',   color: 'orange'},
    {name: 'grape',       color: 'purple'},
    {name: 'banana',      color: 'yellow'},
    {name: 'grapefruit',  color: 'orange'},
    {name: 'watermelon',  color: 'green'},
    {name: 'strawberry',  color: 'red'},
    {name: 'apple',       color: 'red'},
    {name: 'pear',        color: 'green'},
    {name: 'pineapple',   color: 'yellow'},
    {name: 'kiwi',        color: 'green'},
    ];
    
    // only the name   
    var green_Names = [];
    fruits.map(function(fruit){ 
        if(fruit.color === 'green') green_Names.push( fruit.name );
    });
    var notGreen_Names = [];
    fruits.map(function(fruit){ 
         if(fruit.color !== 'green')  notGreen_Names.push( fruit.name )
    });

    // the full Objects
    var green = fruits.filter(function(fruit){ 
        return fruit.color === 'green'
    });
    var notGreen = fruits.filter(function(fruit){ 
        return fruit.color !== 'green'
    });
  
  
  var el = document.getElementById('el'); 
  el.innerHTML = 'Only the names : <br><br>';
  el.innerHTML += 'green_Names : <pre>' + JSON.stringify(green_Names ,null, ' ') + '</pre>';
  
  
  el.innerHTML += 'notGreen_Names : <pre>' + JSON.stringify(notGreen_Names ,null, ' ') + '</pre>';
  
  el.innerHTML += 'The full objects : <br><br>';
  
  el.innerHTML += 'Green : <pre>' + JSON.stringify(green ,null, ' ') + '</pre>';
  el.innerHTML+= 'NotGreen : <pre>' + JSON.stringify(notGreen ,null, ' ') + '</pre>';
```

```html
<div id='el'></div>
```

```
    // only the names
    var green_Names = [];
    fruits.map(function(fruit){ 
        if(fruit.color === 'green') green_Names.push( fruit.name );
    });
    var notGreen_Names = [];
    fruits.map(function(fruit){ 
         if(fruit.color !== 'green')  notGreen_Names.push( fruit.name )
    });

    // the full Objects
    var green = fruits.filter(function(fruit){ 
        return fruit.color === 'green'
    });
    var notGreen = fruits.filter(function(fruit){ 
        return fruit.color !== 'green'
    });
```

this is what could do the trick !

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript `filter` on your fruits array like so:

```js
var fruits = [{
  name: 'nectarine',
  color: 'orange'
}, {
  name: 'grape',
  color: 'purple'
}, {
  name: 'banana',
  color: 'yellow'
}, {
  name: 'grapefruit',
  color: 'orange'
}, {
  name: 'watermelon',
  color: 'green'
}, {
  name: 'strawberry',
  color: 'red'
}, {
  name: 'apple',
  color: 'red'
}, {
  name: 'pear',
  color: 'green'
}, {
  name: 'pineapple',
  color: 'yellow'
}, {
  name: 'kiwi',
  color: 'green'
}, ];

var green = [];


var green = fruits.filter(function(fruit) {
  return fruit.color === "green";
});

console.log(green);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with **filter**:

```
const notGreen1 = fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.color !== 'green');

console.log(notGreen1);
```

Example with **for loop**:

```
function removeColor(originalArray, color) {
   const newArray = [];

   for(let i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
      if(originalArray[i].color !== color) {
         newArray.push(originalArray[i]);
      }
   }
   return newArray;
}

const notGreen2 = removeColor(fruits, 'green');
console.log(notGreen2);
```